# Save a document and quotes appears Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm working in MS Dynamics CRM 2015 on-premise and when files are downloaded from dynamics, the file gets downloaded but that name is getting enclosed with quotes (' '). Ex:'gs1630528410565.pdf'.

This behavior exist only in chrome and works perfectly fine in Firefox and Edge.

Comment: Any followup questions?

Answer (score 1):

This is something to do with the issue introduced in particular chrome version.

As a workaround, use Edge or Firefox. Always you can rename the downloaded file, in case of chrome only work environment.

[Read more](https://www.crmug.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=1285&MessageKey=32d6fdee-25b4-4a91-9e1b-34cb7c6549ab&CommunityKey=dc83c23b-ede0-4070-ae7a-dd90859148a6&tab=digestviewer&ReturnUrl=%2Fparticipate%2Fdiscussion-forum)

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing issue with crm 2016 and crm 2016 onprem.
We are using crm 2016 and we face the same issue.
Below is the article mentioning same.

Till now we have to deal with this annoying issue.
Microsoft had same online as well but they fixed it online as they do not prioritize Onprem anymore

By the way do you use chrome as incognito mode?

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/310058/mscrm-2015---downloaded-file-names-are-enclosed-with